# Http image parsing problem

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to set different images by parsing, but I can set only last image.  I don't know where the problem is in this code:

```
public class GridActivity extends Activity{
    private EfficientAdapter adap;
    String strUrl;
    AddAlbumDetailBean aBean;
    XmlParser parser;
    ArrayList<Object>  result;
    ArrayList<Object> data;
    ImageButton btnAdd;
    private Context context;
     static Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos_activity);
        GridView gView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);
        gView.setAdapter(adap);
        /*btnAdd = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnAddPhotos);
            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(GridActivity.this,AddAlbum.class));
                }
            });
         */
    }

    public static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context context;
        String strUrl;
        AddAlbumDetailBean aBean;
        XmlParser parser;
        ArrayList<Object>  result;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
            String  userId = ConstantData.user_id;
            String  albumId = ConstantData.album_id;
            int pageNo = 1;
            int limit = 20;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.5.10/ijoomer_development/index.php?option=com_ijoomer&plg_name=jomsocial&pview=album&ptask=photo_paging&userid="+ ConstantData.user_id +"&sessionid="+ ConstantData.session_id +"&tmpl=component&albumid="+ ConstantData.album_id +"&pageno=1&limit=20");
                StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer("<data><userid>" + userId + "</userid><albumid>" + albumId + "</albumid><pageno>" + pageNo +"</pageno><limit>"+ limit +"</limit></data>");
                StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(strBuffer.toString());
                post.setEntity(strEntity);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();

                String strResponse = convertStreamToString(in);
                parser = new XmlParser(in, new AddAlbumDetailBean());
                result = parser.parse("data", "data");

                String startThumb ="<thumb>";
                String endThumb = "</thumb>";
                String startUrl = "<url>";
                String endUrl = "</url>";
                if (startThumb.equalsIgnoreCase("<thumb>") && endThumb.equalsIgnoreCase("</thumb>"))
                {
                    int startT = strResponse.indexOf(startThumb);
                    int endT = strResponse.indexOf(endThumb);

                    Log.i("startThumb", ""+startT);
                    Log.i("endThumb", ""+endT);

                    String OldThumb =  strResponse.substring(startT, endT);
                    int startUrlindex = OldThumb.indexOf(">");
                    String thumb = OldThumb.substring(startUrlindex + 1).trim();// getting Url from webservice 
                    Log.i("Thu0mb", ""+thumb);
                    URL newurl = new URL(thumb); 
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());// converting Url into Bitmap but dont know how to use bitmap array here 
                    Log.d("Bitmap in ConstantData", ""+bitmap);
                }               


                if (startUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("<url>") && endUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("</url>"))
                {
                    int startL = strResponse.indexOf(startUrl);
                    int endL = strResponse.indexOf(endUrl);

                    Log.i("startUrl", ""+startL);
                    Log.i("endUrl", ""+endL);

                    String OldUrl =  strResponse.substring(startL, endL);
                    int startUrlindex = OldUrl.indexOf(">");
                    String url = OldUrl.substring(startUrlindex + 1).trim(); 


                }                           
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.iconImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    private int pos = position;
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,GridActivity.class));
                    }
                });

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


                    Log.d("Bitmap in ConstantData", ""+bitmap);
                    holder.iconImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            ImageView iconImage;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 5; // if i m trying to return result.size(); getting error and returning 5 i can only get 5 images  
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }



    }
    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream in)
    throws IOException {


        if (in != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                //  in.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {       
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

Through this code i am trying to set image into the dynamic gridview using adapter....
but i can set only last image into the gridview so i dont know how to use bitmap array

Comment: the problem is not on how to set the images, the problem is about asking a question in an acceptable way...

Comment: @WarrenFaith I've tried to salvage the question

Comment: so what should i do now?

Comment: edit your post and explain better what you're trying to do. Parsing what? Setting images where? how? Have you tried standard debugging techniques? (printing messages to check variable contents, breakpoints...) Also, if you can, leave out the code that you know can't be the problem, because it's a lot of code and we don't really like code *that much* ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems on your code:

- your bitmap is static, so you overriding it...
- you have no loop, so you have only the same bitmap "parsed"

(after that I stopped looking)

Try to clean up your code and try to debug step by step so that you understand what your code does...

update:

some tips:

- use AsyncTask to request the XML and parse it there
- when finished fill the adapter with the parsed image urls

Comment: you should encapsulate your XML parsing. While you parse, you should fill a list of image paths and after the finished parsing you can loop over the paths and get all images... also edited my answer